# Como evitar que el evento click se ejecute al seleccionar una opcion?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

les comento tengo un select que se llena de manera dinámica al ingresar una sucursal y un rango de fechas, lo configure para que ese select se complete con los empleados una vez que se apreta ese mismo select con el evento click. El problema surge que cuando me carga la lista de empleados y selecciono 1 cualquiera, se vuelve a ejecutar la peticion ajax y me cambia automaticamente al primero de la lista. Un ejemplo mas grafico seria, al hacer click en el select me muestra a, b y c, cuando hago click en c me selecciona a que en realidad es como que se ejecuta la funcion nuevamente. He leido en alguna pagina de usar el evento one pero el problema esta en que si cambio de sucursal me siguen figurando los empleados de la sucursal que se selecciono primero, tambien probe con el evento change y directamente no se llena con los empleados, probe con e.preventDefault y directamente no funciona. Les comparto el codigo de como lo tengo configurado a ver si me pueden echar una mano. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#usuario").on("click", function(e) {
                        var dFec = $('#dFec').val();
                        var hFec = $('#hFec').val();
                        var sucursal= $('#sucursal').val();
                    llenaUsuario(sucursal,dFec,hFec);
                });
            });
function llenaUsuario(sucursal,dFec,hFec){
            var request = $.ajax({
                                url: "getUsuario.php",
                                method: "POST",
                                data: {sucursal: sucursal, dFec:dFec, hFec:hFec},
                                dataType: "html",
                                error: function(){
                                    alert("error petición ajax");
                              },
                            });
                            request.done(function( msg ) {
                                $( "#usuario" ).html(msg);
                                });
                    }
```

Comment: Hola. Esto tal vez no justifique una **respuesta en propiedad**, porque es muy simple: **Usa el método [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)** Debes usarlo ojalá como primera línea del método que uses para procesar el evento. Eso garantiza que el comportamiento normal se anule y que **no se propague a otros elementos del DOM** que pudieran responder.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo probe con stopImmediatePropagation y con Event.stopPropagation(), inmediatamente despues de $("#usuario").on("click", function(e) { pero sin embargo no funciona, queda 1 segundo seleccionada la opcion y vuelve a la primera de la lista.

Comment: ¿ usaste e.stopPropagation(); ? (perdona la duda) porque estás pasando el evento como **e** en el controlador de evento que muestras en el comentario. **Ah!** si necesitas que se mantenga la selección de la opción debes asegurarte que se asigne el atributo selected.

Comment: @quevedo si, use ambas y no funciona. Lo probe en otros navegadores para descartar que sea un tema de Chrome y no hace nada. como seria esto  que mencionas? lo de asignar el atributo select.

Answer (score 0):

La función se ejecutará del DOM de id 'usuario' en cada click.
Como indicas es un `<select/>` que llamará a la función `onClick` en cada evento de `'click'`.
Escogiste esta opción por motivo *'X'*, independientemente de la elección bajo este contexto deseas controlar de que el evento no se dispare en cada `click` al `<select/>`.
Puedes atacar el problema usando *semáforos*, poner *bloqueos*, con *observadores*, etc.

Yo voy a ofrecerte una mezcla de intento de semáforo con un intento de observador cómo primera opción, tal vez un poco más *compleja* comparada a la opción número dos.

Y de segunda opción una un poco más económica en código, pero con un inconveniente que puedes notar si realizas algunas pruebas de *esfuerzo* o *estrés* al `<select/>` (no estoy seguro si ocurra algún error -tienes que hacer la prueba de estrés tu mismo).

Mayor detalle en los comentarios del código.

1. Opción Uno

   ```
   function llenaUsuario(sucursal, dFec, hFec) {
    var request = $.ajax({
            url: 'getUsuario.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {sucursal: sucursal, dFec: dFec, hFec: hFec},
            dataType: 'html',
            error: function(){
                alert('error petición ajax');
          },
        });
    request.done(function( msg ) {
        // lo primero es capturar el html() dentro del <select/> usuario
        // vamos a limpiar el select de espacios, saltos de linea y tabulaciones (OJO yo hago esto por que no tengo idea de que formato de texto del html entrega tu servicio)
        // si tu conoces el formato de respuesta de tu servicio y es siempre el adecuado no es necesario que limpies.
        // Básicamente lo que haré es comparar el html anterior con el actual, si son iguales entonces no voy actualizar el contenido del <select/> usuario

        var htmlAnteriorSelectUsuario = $('#usuario').html(); // recuperamos el contenido ANTERIOR
        var htmlActualizarSelectUsuario = msg; // recuperamos el contenido ACTUALIZAR

        // como digo lo de abajo es por que no tengo idea del formato de tu servicio entre las etiquetas opcion, usalo si tienes problemas con el formato de las opciones
        // htmlAnteriorSelectUsuario = htmlAnteriorSelectUsuario.replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('   ','').replaceAll(' ','');
        // htmlActualizarSelectUsuario = htmlActualizarSelectUsuario.replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('   ','').replaceAll(' ','');

        // Ahora comparo, si son diferentes pues actualizo el contenido de usuario
        // la función localeCompare() devuelve 0 si los string son iguales
        if(htmlAnteriorSelectUsuario.localeCompare(htmlActualizarSelectUsuario) != 0) {
            // actualizamos el contenido del <select/> por que fueron diferentes.
            $('#usuario').html(msg);
        }
    });
   }
   ```
2. Opción Dos

   ```
   function llenaUsuario(sucursal, dFec, hFec) {
    var request = $.ajax({
            url: 'getUsuario.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {sucursal: sucursal, dFec: dFec, hFec: hFec},
            dataType: 'html',
            error: function(){
                alert('error petición ajax');
          },
        });
    request.done(function( msg ) {
        // Recuperar el valor seleccionado del <select/> 'usuario' antes de actualizar el contenido con la respuesta del servidor
        // luego mandar a llamar a .val(valorseleccionado);
        var valorSeleccionadoPrevio = $('#usuario').val(); // capturamos el valor seleccionado previo a la actualización
        $('#usuario').html(msg); // actualizamos el contrenido html del <select/>
        $('#usuario').val(valorSeleccionadoPrevio); // cargamos el valor seleccionado previamente como valor del <selec/>
    });
   }
   ```

Espero esto pueda ayudarte a solucionar tu problema, suerte.

---

### ***[Edición]***

Dado lo conversado en los comentarios, tomaremos la opción 2 para crear una validación completa evaluando los valores de los 3 pre requisitos para `llenaUsuario()` (mandar la petición AJAX una vez tenemos los tres valores)

```
$('#dFec').change(function() {
     // acciones previas...
     validarDatos();
     // otras acciones...
});

$('#hFec').change(function() {
     // acciones previas...
     validarDatos();
     // otras acciones...
});

$('#sucursal').change(function() {
     // acciones previas...
     validarDatos();
     // otras acciones...
});

function validarDatos() {
     var dFec = $('#dFec').val();
     var hFec = $('#hFec').val();
     var sucursal = $('#sucursal').val();
     if( isValidValue(dFec) &&
         isValidValue(hFec) &&
         isValidValue(sucursal) ) {
        llenaUsuario(sucursal, dFec, hFec); // mandamos a llamar a la función de la opción 2
     }
}

// si el valor es valido o no.
function isValidValue(valueToEvaluate) {
   if(valueToEvaluate != null && 
      valueToEvaluate != undefined && 
      valueToEvaluate.length > 0) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Diego, primeramente muchas gracias por la ayuda, con la opcion 1 sigue haciendo lo mismo, pero con la opcion 2 selecciona bien la opcion elegida. El problema que tengo con esto es que al hacerle el primer click me muestra el select vacio, tengo que hacerle click 2 veces para que muestre a los usuarios. Por lo tanto y para depurar un poco el codigo, como podria hacer para cuando detecte que los campos sucursal y fechas que tienen informacion, se ejecute la peticion ajax y se llene el select de usuarios sin tener que hacerle click?

Comment: bueno, puedes crear los eventos de `change` en cada uno de esos elementos (fecha, hora y sucursal), comprobar que si los tres valores de los elementos de fecha, hora y sucursal ya tienen un valor distinto de `null` o `undefined` o `texto en blanco`, entonces mande la petición Ajax al servidor para obtener los usuario y cargarlo en el elemento `usuario`, me parece raro que la opción uno no te funcione, quiere decir que tu servicio para la misma petición (que debería responder lo mismo si no hay cambios en la información de usuario) puede dar una respuestas de texto distintas.

Comment: Tu problema tiene distintas soluciones, pero no tengo la visión de código suficiente (para saber que tienes implementado y ayudarte a corregir sobre lo que haz hecho), la idea es sobre lo que tienes hacer ajustes, por que pasarte código de como podrías hacerlo, te terminaría pasando muchas formas distintas de realizarlo.

Comment: Diego, vos me decis que cuando seleccione una sucursal mande una peticion, y al elegir ambas fecha  haga lo mismo, lo cual mandaria 3 peticiones ajax, la pregunta es, en que momento tendria que mandar la funcion llenaUsuarios con las 3 variables necesarias para ejecutar la query que llena el select de usuarios. Me vas aclarando el panorama bastante lo cual te lo agradezco demasiado, pero no le encuentro la forma o la manera de hacerlo.

Comment: dentro de cada evento `change` que haz creado de los 3 elementos, realiza `var fecha = $('#fecha').val(); var hora = $('#hora').val(); var sucursal = $('#sucursal').val();` con eso tienes los 3 datos que luego debes verificar si esos valores son validos (de acuerdo a tus criterios, o criterios generales debe ser diff de `null`, `undefined` y `legnth > 0`) sí cumplen mandas la función de `llenaUsuario()`.

Comment: la verdad que sos un genio, hice exactamente eso que me decis y perfecto, puse que la peticion ajax se ejecute en cada evento change, lo cual tambien ayuda a que no importa el orden que el usuario llene los campos, sino que cuando detecte que estan los 3 campos completos, se va a ejecutar la peticion y llenar el select de usuarios. Te agradezco mucho por la ayuda, lo cual tambien me ayuda para otras cosas que tenia en mente. Te pido si podes agregar la respuesta ultima que me diste, asi te la valido. Saludos

Comment: Listo, editare para colocar la solución a tu problema restante. Muchas gracias.